# Is it possible to run clang with llc flags

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

Is there a way to run the clang and add llc flags ? I want to use "-print-after-all", "-print-before-all", "-debug-only" ... without having to use the .bc file in between.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Additional arguments can be passed to LLVM's option parser with `-mllvm`. For your scenario this would look something like this:

```
clang [...] -mllvm -print-after-all
```

Comment: how did you find it ? where it is written ?

Comment: The `-mllvm` option is part of the (very long) list you get from `clang -help`. I  agree that it is not very obvious.