# Xcode - How to compile with "-fexhaustive-register-search" - needed for linker crash

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, clang, llvm

We're currently facing a linker crash when compiling our App in Xcode:

```
register allocation failed: maximum depth for recoloring reached. Use -fexhaustive-register-search to skip cutoffs
```

Therefore we tried to add:

```
-fexhaustive-register-search
```

to our linker flags, but it doesn't work and we get this:

```
unknown argument: '-fexhaustive-register-search'
```

So what can we do?

Comment: register allocation sounds like a compiler/codegen-stage error, rather than a link error. Did you try adding that flag to your compiler flags instead?

Comment: Good idea indeed! I added it to one file's compiler flags, though I get the this error: ```clang: error: unknown argument: '-fexhaustive-register-search'```
Is there some Xcode-wide-setting that you meant?
Do you have any insight what might trigger this and how we could work around that?

Comment: Got it, that's a terrible error message ...

Comment: How do you mean? The new one is terrible - the old one? All of them? ;)

Comment: The original error message was outright wrong, and also didn't give you any idea about how to _use_ the suggested parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The flag you need is used by `llc`, passed via the language frontend. For example:

```
clang++ -mllvm -exhaustive-register-search ...
```

---

### References

- searching for `clang '-fexhaustive-register-search'` as per the error message, takes us here:

  https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140407/212477.html
- following the embedded link to the RegAllocGreedy.cpp source, and jumping to the latest version, brings us here:

  https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/CodeGen/RegAllocGreedy.cpp?view=markup
- searching in that file reveals the `exhaustive-register-search` parameter, and there was a comment in the original archived mail suggesting the `-f` in the original error message was removed (so the message is wrong)

  > > We don't normally name these things with a 'f' in front inside LLVM proper. That's a Clang thing
  >
  > Good point!
  >
  > I’ll remove it.

  (so, the command-line argument became `-exhaustive-register-search`, but the error messages further down the same file still say `-fexhaustive-register-search`)
- searching for the new argument with `clang 'exhaustive-register-search'` gets us here https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26338 which reveals that it's an argument to `llc`, the codegen backend, which makes sense
- more searching eventually brings us [back to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700766/is-it-possible-to-run-clang-with-llc-flags), giving us the correct incantation.

Comment: Thanks, that's really enlightening. Unfortunately, I still don't get it to work as of now. I added the flag "-llvm -exhaustive-register-search" to all my source files and I'm getting this ```clang: warning: -llvm: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-e xhaustive-register-search' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
error: register allocation failed: maximum depth for recoloring reached. Use -fexhaustive-register-search to skip cutoffs``` I also tried without the "-llvm" but no luck. It seems like something with first letter.

Comment: After all that, I mis-typed the important bit. Use `-mllvm -exhaustive-register-search`, as in the linked Q&A

Comment: Thanks, I added this flag to all my source files but unfortunately, my compile will still not run through: ```error: register allocation failed: maximum depth for recoloring reached. Use -fexhaustive-register-search to skip cutoffs
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```.  This is a really really weird compiler error. I tried Xcode 8.3.3 in the meantime and there it works by the way. But in Xcode 9.1 - it does not work.